# $_POST Variables Empty when Using Stream_context_create

Tags: php

The Post looks like this.

```
 $data = array('icd9' => $icd9, 'cpt' => $cpt, 'session_id'=> $session_id);
    $url = $api_location."rarity/".$session_id;
    $params = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => $data));
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if (!$fp){
       return "Error";
    }
    $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);

    $results = $response;//json_decode($response);

    return $results;
```

The Block on the api_location server looks like this:

```
if ($_POST['session_id']){
    $fh = fopen('/interaction/rarity_req/alive.txt','w');
    fwrite($fh,'\r\n'.date("Y-m-d - H:i:s"));
    fclose($fh);
    $session_id = $_POST['session_id'];
    $cpt = $_POST['cpt'];
    $icd9 = $_POST['icd9'];
}else{
    $fh = fopen('/interaction/rarity_req/died.txt','w');
    fwrite($fh, '\r\n'.date("Y-m-d - H:i:s"));
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Any Ideas? I know I could install cURL to do this, but was trying to avoid it if at all possible because this is so simple. Was basing it off of this blog post: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn your data into a URL-encoded string:

```
$params = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => http_build_query($data)) );
```

Comment: Awesome that was it. I'll accept this answer in 2 minutes when I can.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see you encoding the data for the POST with `http_build_query` nor manually. Without doing that you would need to read the raw request content on target side and parse it manually :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using the incorrect format for your data variable. Check [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#90411) on the PHP manual page